# Log-computations in Python

Tags: python, scipy, large-data

I'm looking to compute something like:

[image: formula]

Where `f(i)` is a function that returns a real number in `[-1,1]` for any `i` in `{1,2,...,5000}`.

Obviously, the result of the sum is somewhere in `[-1,1]`, but when I can't seem to be able to compute it in Python using straight forward coding, as `0.55000` becomes `0` and `comb(5000,2000)` becomes `inf`, which result in the computed sum turning into `NaN`.

The required solution is to use log on both sides.

That is using the identity `a × b = 2log(a) + log(b)`, if I could compute `log(a)` and `log(b)` I could compute the sum, even if `a` is big and `b` is almost `0`.

**So I guess what I'm asking is if there's an easy way of computing**

```
log2(scipy.misc.comb(5000,2000))
```

So I could compute my sum simply by

```
sum([2**(log2comb(5000,i)-5000) * f(i) for i in range(1,5000) ])
```

---

@abarnert's solution, while working for the 5000 figure addresses the problem by increasing the precision in which the comb is computed. This works for this example, but doesn't scale, as the memory required would significantly increase if instead of 5000 we had 1e7 for example.

Currently, I'm using a workaround which is ugly, but keeps memory consumption low:

```
log2(comb(5000,2000)) = sum([log2 (x) for x in 1:5000])-sum([log2 (x) for x in 1:2000])-sum([log2 (x) for x in 1:3000])
```

**Is there a way of doing so in a readable expression?**

Comment: How much memory do you think integers take? `comb(1000000, 200000)` is about `2**721918`, which means it takes about 720K to store exactly. And, since you only need each one transiently, who cares?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum

[image: formula]

is the expectation of `f` with respect to a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) with `n = 5000` and `p = 0.5`.

You can compute this with [scipy.stats.binom.expect](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html#scipy.stats.binom):

```
import scipy.stats as stats

def f(i):
    return i
n, p = 5000, 0.5
print(stats.binom.expect(f, (n, p), lb=0, ub=n))
# 2499.99999997
```

Also note that as `n` goes to infinity, with `p` fixed, the binomial distribution [approaches the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Limiting_distributions) with mean `np` and variance `np*(1-p)`. Therefore, for large `n` you can instead compute:

```
import math
print(stats.norm.expect(f, loc=n*p, scale=math.sqrt((n*p*(1-p))), lb=0, ub=n))
# 2500.0
```

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: @unutbu has answered the *real* question, but I'll leave this here in case `log2comb(n, k)` is useful to anyone.

---

`comb(n, k)` is n! / ((n-k)! k!), and n! can be computed using the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) `gamma(n+1)`. Scipy provides the function `scipy.special.gamma`.  Scipy also provides `gammaln`, which is the log (natural log, that is) of the Gamma function.

So `log(comb(n, k))` can be computed as `gammaln(n+1) - gammaln(n-k+1) - gammaln(k+1)`

For example, log(comb(100, 8)) (after executing `from scipy.special import gammaln`):

```
In [26]: log(comb(100, 8))
Out[26]: 25.949484949043022

In [27]: gammaln(101) - gammaln(93) - gammaln(9)
Out[27]: 25.949484949042962
```

and log(comb(5000, 2000)):

```
In [28]: log(comb(5000, 2000))  # Overflow!
Out[28]: inf

In [29]: gammaln(5001) - gammaln(3001) - gammaln(2001)
Out[29]: 3360.5943053174142
```

(Of course, to get the base-2 logarithm, just divide by `log(2)`.)

For convenience, you can define:

```
from math import log
from scipy.special import gammaln

def log2comb(n, k):
    return (gammaln(n+1) - gammaln(n-k+1) - gammaln(k+1)) / log(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, [`comb`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html) gives you a `float64`, which overflows and gives you `inf`.

But if you pass `exact=True`, it gives you a Python variable-sized `int` instead, which can't overflow (unless you get so ridiculously huge you run out of memory).

And, while you can't use `np.log2` on an `int`, you can use Python's `math.log2`.

So:

```
math.log2(scipy.misc.comb(5000, 2000, exact=True))
```

---

As an alternative, you relative that n choose k is defined as `n!k / k!`, right? You can reduce that to `∏(i=1...k)((n+1-i)/i)`, which is simple to compute.

Or, if you want to avoid overflow, you can do it by alternating `* (n-i)` and `/ (k-i)`.

Which, of course, you can also reduce to adding and subtracting logs. I think looping in Python and computing 4000 logarithms is going to be slower than looping in C and computing 4000 multiplications, but we can always vectorize it, and then, it might be faster. Let's write it and test:

```
In [1327]: n, k = 5000, 2000
In [1328]: %timeit math.log2(scipy.misc.comb(5000, 2000, exact=True))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop
In [1329]: %timeit np.log2(np.arange(n-k+1, n+1)).sum() - np.log2(np.arange(1, k+1)).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.1 µs per loop
```

Of course if you're more concerned with memory instead of time… well, this obviously makes it worse. We've got 2000 8-byte floats instead of one 608-byte integer at a time. And if you go up to 100000, 20000, you get 20000 8-byte floats instead of one 9K integer. And at 1000000, 200000, it's 200000 8-byte floats vs. one 720K integer.

I'm not sure why either way is a problem for you. Especially given that you're using a listcomp instead of a genexpr, and therefore creating an unnecessary list of 5000, 100000, or 1000000 Python floats—24MB is not a problem, but 720K is? But if it is, we can obviously just do the same thing iteratively, at the cost of some speed:

```
r = sum(math.log2(n-i) - math.log2(k-i) for i in range(n-k))
```

This isn't *too* much slower than the `scipy` solution, and it never uses more than a small constant number of bytes (a handful of Python floats). (Unless you're on Python 2, in which case… just use `xrange` instead of `range` and it's back to constant.)

---

As a side note, why *are* you using a list comprehension instead of an NumPy array with vectorized operations (for speed, and also a bit of compactness) or a generator expression instead of a list comprehension (for no memory usage at all, at no cost to speed)?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, but this seems inefficient. I don't mind losing the precision, but wishes to keep memory usage low. the least significant digits of the log are useless anyways here, as the result, after exponentiation will be kept in float64, right?
My current solution avoids it by computing the log myself (that is log2(comb(5000,2000)) = sum([log2 (x) for x in 1:5000])-sum([log2 (x) for x in 1:2000])-sum([log2 (x) for x in 1:3000]), but it looks mighty ugly).

Comment: @RB: It is somewhat inefficient, but we're talking about 1ms on my laptop, you're doing this 4999 times, so… is 5 seconds a problem?

Comment: This seems more memory-inefficient than runtime inefficient. I'm concerned about the memory required by this exact=True, even if for 5000 and 2000 it's still low, this doesn't give a general solution. Like I said, I'm willing to lose a bit of precision/runtime for the sake of the memory consumption.

Comment: i.e. what if instead of 5000 I had 100000?

Comment: @RB: OK, see my updated answer. This sounds like an extreme case of premature optimization, but I've optimized it for you anyway.