# Calculate very large number using python

Tags: python, numbers, scipy, calculator

I'm trying to calculate (3e28 choose 2e28)/2^(3e28). I tried scipy.misc.comb to calculate 3e28 choose 2e28 but it gave me inf. When I calculate 2^(3e28), it raised OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large'). How can I compute or estimate (3e28 choose 2e28)/2^(3e28)?

Comment: How about doing some math and applying Stirling's approximation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Answer (score 4):

Use Stirling's approximation (which is very accurate in the 1e10+ range), combined with logarithms:

```
(3e28 choose 2e28) / 2^(3e28) = 3e28! / [(3e28 - 2e28)! * 2e28!] / 2^(3e28)
= e^ [log (3e28!) - log((3e28-2e28)!) - log(2e28!) - 3e28 * log(2)]
```

and from there apply Stirling's approximation:

```
log n! ~= log(sqrt(2*pi*n)) + n*log(n) - n
```

and you'll get your answer.

---

Here's an example of how accurate this approximation is:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(math.factorial(100))
363.73937555556347
>>> math.log((2*math.pi*100)**.5) + 100*math.log(100) - 100
363.7385422250079
```

For 100!, it's off by less than 0.01% in log-space.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute this ratio with the normal approximation to the binomial for large `n`. When `n` is large, `k` has to be relatively close to `n/2` for `(n choose k) / 2^n` to not be negligible.

## Code

Here's some code that will compute this:

```
def n_choose_k_over_2_pow_n(n, k):
    # compute the mean and standard deviation of the normal
    # approximation
    mu = n / 2.
    sigma = np.sqrt(n) * 1/4.

    # now transform to a standard normal variable
    z = (k - mu) / sigma

    return 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * np.exp(-1/2. * z**2)
```

So that:

```
>>> n_choose_k_over_2_pow_n(3e28, 2e28)
0.0
>>> n_choose_k_over_2_pow_n(3e28, 1.5e28)
0.3989422804014327
```

As you can see, the computation underflows. A solution is to compute the *log* of the answer, which we can do with this code:

```
def log_n_choose_k_over_2_pow_n(n, k):
    # compute the mean and standard deviation of the normal
    # approximation
    mu = n / 2.
    sigma = np.sqrt(n) * 1/4.

    # now transform to a standard normal variable
    z = (k - mu) / sigma

    # return the log of the answer
    return -1./2 * (np.log(2 * np.pi) + z**2)
```

Another quick check:

```
>>> log_n_choose_k_over_2_pow_n(3e28, 2e28)
-6.6666666666666638e+27
>>> log_n_choose_k_over_2_pow_n(3e28, 1.5e28)
-0.91893853320467267
```

If we exponentiate these, we'll get our previous answers.

## Explanation

We can do this by an appeal to results from statistics. The binomial distribution is given by:

```
P(K = k) = (n choose k) p^k * p^(n-k)
```

For large `n`, this is well-approximated by the normal distribution with mean `n*p` and variance `n*p*(1-p)`.

Set `p` to be `1/2`. Then we have:

```
P(K = k) = (n choose k) (1/2)^k * (1/2)^(n-k)
         = (n choose k) (1/2)^n
         = (n choose k) / (2^n)
```

Which is precisely the form of your ratio. Therefore, after a transformation to a standard normal variable with mean `n/2` and variance `n/4`, we can compute your ratio by a simple evaluation of the standard normal distribution pdf.

Comment: Yes, but maybe the OP wants to know what the order of magnitude is: 1e-3000 might be close to zero, but it isn't zero.

Comment: @nneonneo Fair enough. The order of magnitude can be estimated from the same line of reasoning: The result isn't any bigger than `(3e28)^-1`.

Comment: The result turns out to be an astonishing `e^(-1.699e+27)`, which is absolutely miniscule. That's smaller than (3e28)^-1 (which is about `e^-65.571`) by over **10^20 orders of magnitude**. (These sorts of numbers really give me a headache sometimes...)

Comment: Now here's a real challenge: Calculate `(3e28 choose (3e28/2))/(2^(3e28))`. It is, by your reasoning, "essentially zero". But in fact it isn't. (I'm having trouble computing it because I'm getting catastrophic cancellation in log-space...which generally indicates that the results are near zero in log-space, which means they aren't negligible)

Comment: @nneonneo Haha. That's why I'm glad that I can generally just ignore them in my line of work.

Comment: @nneonneo I've added more to my answer... I think the solution for `(3e28 choose (3e28/2))/(2^(3e28))` should be approximately `phi(0)`, where `phi` is the pdf of the standard normal. You're right that this is not at all negligible. In my original argument I didn't make clear that the fact that `k` was "far" from `n/2` was important for bounding the answer close to zero, but this longer response should clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `log2comb` from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938888/log-computations-in-python/26940133#26940133):

```
from math import log
from scipy.special import gammaln


def log2comb(n, k):
    return (gammaln(n+1) - gammaln(n-k+1) - gammaln(k+1)) / log(2)


log2p = log2comb(3e28, 2e28) - 3e28
print "log2p =", log2p
```

which prints

```
log2p = -2.45112497837e+27
```

So the base-2 *logarithm* of your number is about -2.45e27.  If you try to compute 2**log2p, you get 0.  That is, the number is smaller than the smallest positive number representable with standard 64 bit floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are python libraries that allow you to do arbitrary precision arithmetic. For example mpmath as used in SymPy.

You will have to rewrite your code to use the library functions though.

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/mpmath/basics.html?highlight=precision

Edit: I just noticed the size of the numbers you are dealing with - much too large for my suggestion.