# dealing with large powers python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program dealing with large numbers and large powers. Example number is 632382^518061.
In python 3 I have tried:

```
from math import pow
number = pow(632382,518061)
print(number)
```

And the output is:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

I also tried:

```
number = 632382**518061
print(number)
```

Where there is never an output and it remains empty(I know this is because the number is extremely large).
Thank you.

Comment: The second code "works", it just take "a while" to output such a large number (it has roughly 3.000.000 digits). Is your issue calculating or showing the number?

Comment: If it's simply too big to calculate in your very finite computer memory, you may just have to look at approximations. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517308/476

Comment: @deceze It's possible to calculate using Python's integer arithmetic (the second code example). The number takes roughly 1.3 MB of memory.