# How to multiply a super large number with a super small number in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing some probability calculation.
In one of my task, I need to multiply the combination number of choose 8000 samples from 10000 items with 0.8**8000.
The combination number is a long `long-number`, and with the help of numpy, I get the result of `0.8**8000` as `5.2468172239242176864e-776`.
But when I try to multiply these two numbers, I got `[9]    34845 segmentation fault  ipython -i`.
How can I do such multiplication then?

PS: This is a piece of my code

```
import numpy
d2 = numpy.float128(0.8) ** 8000
d1 = 165555575235503558460892983752748337696863078099010763950122624527927836980322780662408249953188062227721112100054260160204180655980717428736444016909193193353770953722788106404786520413339850951599929567643032803416164290936680088121145665954509987077953596641237451927908536624592636591471456488142060812180933761408708169972797751139799352908109763166895772281109195968567911923343187466596002627570139321755043803267091330804414889831229832744256038117150720178689066894068507531026417815624234453195871008113238128934831837842040515600131726096039123279876153916504647241693083829553081901075278042326502699324012014817969085443550523855284341221708045253558716789811929298590803855947461554713178815399150688529048306222786951038548880400191620565711291586700534540755526276938422405001345270278335726581375322976014611332999126216550500951669985289322635729053541565465940744524663726205818866513444952048185208697438054246674199211750006230637806394882672053335493831407089830994135058867370833787098758113596190447219426121568324685764151601296948654893782399960327514764114467176417125060133454019708700782282480571935020898204763471121684913190735908414301826140125010936910161942130277906874552721346626800201093026689035996876035329180150478191582393837824731994055511844267891121846403164857127885959745644323971338513739214928092232132691519007718752719466750891748327404893783451436251805894736392433617289459646429204124129760273396235033220480921175386059331059354409267348067375581516003852060360378571075522650956157791058846993826792047806030332676423336065499519953076910418838626376480202828151673161942289092221049283902410699951912366163469099917310239336454637062482599733606299329923589714875696509548029668358723465427602758225427644633549944802010973352599970041918971524450218727345622721744933664742499521140235707102217164259438766026322532351208348119475549696983427008567651685921355966036780080415723688044325099562693124488758728102729947753752228785786200998322978801432511608341549234067324280214361346940194251357867820535466891356019219904248859277399657389914429390105240751239760865282709465029549690591863591028864648910033430400L
print d1 * d2
```

Comment: These numbers are so huge and so small.... Do they even make sense? Can't you reduce them before you need to multiply them?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938888/log-computations-in-python?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't expect a segfault though, whatever the domain. I would report this as a bug in ipython or numpy.

Comment: @RedX my first thought was that this is an evaluation of the [binomial distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). But in that case, there seems to be a missing term of 0.2**2000 :)

Comment: Second @WarrenWeckesser 's comment. You really want to work with log values with probabilities, and there's a lot of good info in that post on how to do it, like using gammaln.

Comment: The multiplication between float128 and Python-long seems undefined/unimplemented. The segfault/"maximum recursion exceeded" is a bug though, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6455

Answer (score 6):

When multiplying an extremely large number by an extremely small number, working with floats can introduce huge inaccuracies.  In your case, the magnitude of the numbers is causing overflow errors, so you have bigger problems than just inaccuracies!

Whenever you find yourself in this situation, it can be useful to first **check if it is possible to stay in the integer domain**, and "massage" the numbers a little first.  In your case, it is possible and I'll explain how below.

One operand of the multiplication, the extremely large number, is 8000 samples from 10000 items.  Use the closed form equation for the number of combinations, where your sample size `n` is 10000 and the subset size `r` is 8000.  Exclam (!) here is factorial, which you can find in `math.factorial` in python.

```
C(n,r) = n! / r! (n - r)!
```

The other operand `0.8 ** 8000` is the extremely small number, which by index laws is equal to:

```
8**8000 / 10**8000
```

So when we multiply these two numbers together, the answer we want is:

```
     10000! * 8**8000
--------------------------
 8000! * 2000! * 10**8000
```

Let's call this number `x` and then take logarithms of both sides.  Working in the log domain will transform multiplications into additions, and divisions into subtractions, making things more manageable.

```
from math import log, factorial
numerator = log(factorial(10000)) + 8000*log(8)
denominator = log(factorial(8000)) + log(factorial(2000)) + 8000*log(10)
log_x = numerator - denominator
```

Now these numbers are of a magnitude that is usable in python.

You will find that `log_x` is equal to approximately 3214.  You now only need to observe that `exp(log_x) == x` to find your answer.  It is a very large, but finite, number.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: There are no infinities involved here. Where do you think any infinities are introduced?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I have added additional explanation for transforming to "more managable" numbers, and some detail on how to compute the answer.  There is no way to take "the limit" here because there is no sequence from which to take the limit.

Comment: @wim: Thanks for your input on my "answer". :)

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary-precision integers aren't really the way to go for this problem, since you're destroying any precision you had by calling log, so I'll just let `scipy.special.gammaln` speak for itself (but see my edit below):

```
from math import log, factorial
from scipy.special import gammaln

def comp_integral(n, r, p, q):
    numerator = log(factorial(n)) + r*log(8)
    denominator = log(factorial(r)) + log(factorial(n-r)) + r*log(q)
    return numerator - denominator

def comp_gamma(n, r, p, q):
    comb = gammaln(n+1) - gammaln(n-r+1) - gammaln(r+1)
    expon = r*(log(p) - log(q))
    return comb+expon

In [220]: comp_integral(10000, 8000, 8, 10)
Out[220]: 3214.267963130871

In [221]: comp_gamma(10000, 8000, 8, 10)
Out[221]: 3214.2679631308811

In [222]: %timeit comp_integral(10000, 8000, 8, 10)
10 loops, best of 3: 80.3 ms per loop

In [223]: %timeit comp_gamma(10000, 8000, 8, 10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.4 µs per loop
```

Note that the outputs are identical up to 14 digits, but the `gammaln` version is almost 8000 times faster. If you're going to do this a lot, this will count.

EDIT: What `gammaln` does is to compute the natural log of the gamma function. The gamma function can be thought of as a generalization of factorial, in that `factorial(n) == gamma(n+1)`. So `comb(n,r) == gamma(n+1)/(gamma(n-r+1)*gamma(r+1))`. Then taking logs turns it into the form above.

Gamma also has values for [fractional inputs and for negative numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). That doesn't really matter here though.

Comment: ＋1  Good.  I think your answer could do with some explanation of how the gamma function relates to the OP's problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library and it can do this very easily.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.comb(10000,8000) * gmpy2.mpfr('0.8')**8000
mpfr('8.6863984366232171e+1395')
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of wim's great answer, you can also store this number as a `Fraction` by building a list of prime factors, doing any cancellations and multiplying everything together.

I've included a rather naive implementation for this problem. It returns a fraction in less than a minute as is but if you implement slightly smarter factorization you can surely make it even faster.

```
from collections import Counter
from fractions import Fraction
import gmpy2 as gmpy

def get_factors(n):
    factors = Counter()
    factor = 1
    while n != 1:
        factor = int(gmpy.next_prime(factor))
        while not n % factor:
            n //= factor
            factors[factor] += 1
    return factors

factors = Counter()

# multiply by 10000!
for i in range(10000):
  factors += get_factors(i+1)

# multiply by 8^8000
factors[2] += 3*8000

#divide by 2000!
for i in range(2000):
  factors -= get_factors(i+1)

#divide by 8000!
for i in range(8000):
  factors -= get_factors(i+1)

# divide by 10^8000
factors[2] -= 8000
factors[5] -= 8000

# build Fraction
numer = 1
denom = 1
for f,c in factors.items():
    if c>0:
        numer *= f**c
    elif c<0:
        denom *= f**-c

frac = Fraction(numer, denom)
```

Looks like it's around 8.686*10^1395

Comment: Excellent.  `log(8.686e1395)` is approx 3214, in good agreement with my answer.